# An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments in moq framework

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, moq, xunit

having trouble with moq after updating project which based on .netcore beta 5 and updated to rc1. Before updating, test was worked and now I have error: "An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments". Help me please to solve it.

```
[Fact]
public async void ReturnPostUserAnswerResult()
{
    // Arrange
    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<QuestionsToUsers>>();
    var _applicationDbContext = new Mock<ApplicationDbContext>();
    _applicationDbContext.Setup(a => a.QuestionToUsers).Returns(mockSet.Object);
    var controller = new UserQuizController(_applicationDbContext.Object);
    // Act
    var result = new QuestionsToUsers()
    {
        Answer = true,
        QuestionID = 99,
        TestpackID = 99,
        Id = 99,
        UserID = "TestUser"
    };
    await controller.PostUserAnswerResult(result);

    mockSet.Verify(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<QuestionsToUsers>())); //here error
}
```

Comment: So what is the signature of that `Add` method (of `DbSet<>`) now? You get the compile-time error mentioned in the current title of this thread because there is an optional parameter to `Add`. You must give the optional value explicitly in the lambda, or use `It.IsAny<>()` for it.

Answer (score 0):

It has been for a while after question was asked but today I encountered with the same issue.

While I testing masstransit consumer, I need to verify ConsumeContext<> .Defer method.

I just changed

```
_mockConsumeContext.Verify(cc => cc.Defer(It.IsAny<TimeSpan>()), Times.Once);
```

to

```
_mockConsumeContext.VerifySet(cc => cc.Defer(It.IsAny<TimeSpan>()), Times.Once);
```

It solved my problem, may be can solve yours too.